# How do I remove combo box dynamically in C# by pressing a button in runtime?

Tags: c#, forms, dynamic, button

I am currently trying to make a form which works dynamically.
I created a flow layout panel, add button, and remove button on the form.
When I click on the add button, combo box appears inside the panel and keeps adding if I click on add button from top to bottom.

Problem is I don't know how to remove one by one.
For example, if I added three combo box by clicking add button 3 times(say combo box 1, 2, 3), I want to remove them in order 3, 2, 1 as I click remove button.

How do I do this in C#?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
flowLayoutPanel.Controls.RemoveAt(flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count - 1);
```

Refer to [Control.ControlCollection.RemoveAt Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.removeat%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

Comment: And maybe check that flowLayoutPanel.Controls.Count > 0.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a combo box control array to keep track of the combo boxes created, have a look o this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289500%28VS.71%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Try This

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox b1 = new ComboBox();
        b1.BackColor = Color.Blue;

        flp.Controls.Add(b1);

        b1.Text = b1.TabIndex.ToString();

    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (flp.Controls.Count > 0)
        {

            flp.Controls.RemoveAt(flp.Controls.Count - 1);
        }
    }



}
```

}